# Given two samples from N with known variances how to find probability that one sample's variance is two times larger than the other?

Tags: variance, chi-squared-test, f-test

I have two samples with sizes 9 and 11 drawn from two independent normal distributions with variances 21 and 37 respectively. How can I find the probability that the variance of the first sample is two times larger than the other?

Comment: You probably mean to say "test the null hypothesis that the population variance for the second population is less than 2 the magnitude of the population variance for the first population. You wish to reject the null hypothesis in favor of the alternative that the ratio of the 2 variances is >= 2.". Consider that for independent normal distributions the ratio of the two standard deviations is proportional to the ratio of two independent chi square distributions & that ratio has an F distribution with 10 & 8 degrees of freedom.

Comment: You should add the self-study tag.

Comment: To expand on Michael's point, when sampling from continuous distributions the chance that one sample variance is exactly twice another is 0. The probability that one is at least twice the other is a more interesting question and may be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sample comes from a population with a smaller variance
and the second sample from a population with a larger variance.
So it seems unlikely that $S_1^2$ is much larger than $S_2^2,$
and even less likely still that $S_1^2/S_2^2 \ge 2.$ So let's
start with a simulation in R to get an idea just how likely it is
to have $R = S_1^2/S_2^2 \ge 2.$

```
set.seed(914)
r = replicate(10^6,
  var(rnorm(9,0,sqrt(21)))/var(rnorm(11,0,sqrt(37))))
mean(r >= 2)
[1] 0.033342    # aprx P(R >= 2) = 0.0332 (see below)
```

We see that we *can* have $R \ge2,$ but rarely. With a million iterations (pairs of samples), the simulated value $P(R \ge 2)=0.0333$ should be accurate to two or three decimal places.

Now the question
is whether we can express this probability in terms of the F-distribution.

The ratio $F = \frac{S_1^2/\sigma_1^2}{S_2^2/\sigma_2^2}  =
\frac{S_1^2/21}{S_2^2/37}
\sim \mathsf{F}(n_1-1, n_2 - 1) \equiv \mathsf{F}(8, 10).$ 
We need to express this in terms of $R.$ It is easy to see that
$R \ge 2$ is the same as $F \ge 2(37/21) = 74/21.$

So using the CDF `pf` of the appropriate F-distribution ought to
give us nearly the same answer as we got from the simulation, which
it does. The exact answer to four places is $0.0332.$

```
1 - pf(74/21, 8,10)
[1] 0.03316164
```

*Note:* Most printed F-tables are not quite up to the task of evaluating this probability. My printed table shows probability .05 in the upper tail beyond 3.07 and probability 0.025 beyond 3.83. Because 
$72/21 \approx 3.429$ (between 3.07 and 3.83) we know from my table only that $0.025 < P(R \ge 2) <0.05$--*maybe* about halfway between.